# Grunt connect proxy rewrite not works in https

Tags: javascript, angularjs, proxy, gruntjs, grunt-connect-proxy

I try to create a connect proxy by this [article](http://www.hierax.org/2014/01/grunt-proxy-setup-for-yeoman.html). Almost everything is the same in my code, but I need to call something across https protocol.

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
      hostname: '0.0.0.0',
      livereload: 35729
  },
  proxies: [{
    context: ['/foo/product', '/foo/somethingelse'],
    host: 'non-https-domain.com',
    changeOrigin: true
    rewrite: {
      '^/foo': ''
    }
  },{
    context: '/productImages',
    host: 'https-domain.com',
    https: true,
    port: 443,  // just trying
    changeOrigin: true,
    rewrite: {
      '^/productImages': ''
    }
  }],
    livereload: {
    // the same like the article
  }
}
```

The `/product` and the  `/somethingelse` works well, but the `/productImages` not.

I need to call it like this:

```
localhost:9000/productImages/lot/of/directory/and/finally/a/file.jpg
```

and it should call the

```
https://https-domain.com/lot/of/directory/and/finally/a/file.jpg
```

the point is that without `/productImages`. But the replace never happened.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: is there an error? Are you using a self signed SSL cert?

Comment: There is no error, only simple call a wrong url. I don't use Self-signed certificate.

Comment: I'm not 100% positive but I believe you need a self signed cert for when trying to use https on localhost... where is it failing?

Comment: It fails to https://https-domain.com/productImages/lot/of/directory/and/finally/a/file.jpg The server got the call, but with the `/productImages`.

Comment: have you tried without https?

Comment: I have to use https for that call. But the another proxy setting is an example for the non-https call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake: There is only error with the names!

There is a `/product` proxy context for the product list, and a `/productImages` for the images. I use regex to set these names. And the `"^/product"` will replace the `/productImages` too. (I put the `foo` only for testing the rewrite)